# How to use a WIndows 10 tablet as an emulator?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

Hi I am developing a Windows Universal Application and I want to use my Windows 10 Tablet which is connected to my PC by USB as a testing device for my app when I run it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try out remote debugging.

Choose *Remote Machine* as the target device in the project properties.

Choose *Find Device* -> Enter the IP of the tablet in the dialog box shown.

[image]

Install the remote debugging tools in the target device.

You should have Remote debugger open in the target device for the connection to set up.

This link might help - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, when you starting your app, select Device instead of Local Machine.
[image]

Comment: I get an error of The project 'Ward obs Roaming' needs to be deployed before it can be started. So i tick deployed in the configuration manager and I still get the same error.

Comment: Try right click on the name of your project in Solution Explorer and press Deploy.

Comment: I did that as you can see in my comment and i still get the same error

Comment: I didn't speak about deploying through Conf. Manager, but about 'manually' deploying, sometimes it helps. As I said, Solution Manager, right click on project name and choose Deploy. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

> I get an error of The project 'Ward obs Roaming' needs to be deployed before it can be started. So i tick deployed in the configuration manager and I still get the same error.

Can you please check if your tablet can be detected on PC while it connected to PC through USB connection is?

If your PC can detect this tablet, you will need to check whether the "Develper mode" is enabled. To enable this mode, you need to go to the Settings of both your windows 10 tablet and pc for development, then choose "Update & Security", and in the table "For developers", enable the mode "Developer mode".

Check whether you have chosen the right architecture for debugging, you have to select "Device" for it, but the platform can be x86 or x64, you will need to try it.

If you still get the error, you can also create a new empty solution and deploy it to the tablet, this will help you to know whether the problem is with your VS tool or with your solution.

**Important**: When you deploy your project to a device, the device must have the screen unlocked. This also a point which can cause failure of deployment.

As a backup solution, you can try remote debugging, to do this, you may refer to [Deploying and debugging Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).